# ORACLE Program code to use filter and pivot table

Tags: oracle, filter, pivot-table

IN EXCEL SHEET FOR THE BELOW INPUT, I HAVE TO USE FILTER TO “NET” FIRST WHERE NET=APB AND NEED TO FILTER “CODE VALUES” AS WDL, LRTF & NEED TO USE “PIVOT TABLE” TO GET OUTPUT WITH COUNT AS:

BUT **I NEED CODE IN ORACLE TO RUN FOR THE FOLLOWING OUTPUT:-**

INPUT:

| STTID | AMOUNT | NET | CODE |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SVPC12309A | 5000 | NFS | SOP |  |
| SVPC12309A | 10000 | NFS | WDL |  |
| 000DHP11291 | 2500 | APB | WDL |  |
| SVPC12309A | 3000 | CMV | LRTF |  |
| SVPC12309A | 3000 | CMV | WDL |  |
| DHP12341 | 4500 | APB | LRTF |  |
| DHP23451 | 9500 | APB | LRTF |  |
| DHP12341 | 5500 | APB | LRTF |  |

OUTPUT AS:

| STTID | LRTF | WDL | TOTAL |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000DHP11291 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |
| DHP12341 | 2 | 0 | 2 |  |
| DHP23451 | 1 | 0 | 1 |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: You might want to fix THE SHOUTING caps.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want something like

```
select sttid,
       sum( case when code = 'LRTF' then 1 else 0 end ) ltrf,
       sum( case when code = 'WDL' then 1 else 0 end ) wdl,
       sum( case when code in ('WDL', 'LTRF') then 1 else 0 end) total
  from your_table_name
 group by sttid
```

Comment: sir, there 1 and 0 are count, how many times it was there in table. DHP12341 is there 2times for code "LRTF".

Comment: @Tejaswini - Sorry, I'm not sure I understand.  The query I posted would return a LRTF value of 2 for `sttid` "DHP12341" given the sample data you posted.